# Trying to make multiple pie charts with iterative loop, only getting one

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, pie-chart

I am trying to make multiple pie charts using this code:

```
n = 0
perc = list()
while n < len(piedata):
    perc.append(piedata[n+2])
    n += 3
print (perc)
n = 0
fails = list()
while n < len(piedata):
    fails.append(piedata[n+1])
    n += 3
print(fails)

n = 0
titles = list()
while n < len(piedata):
    titles.append(piedata[n])
    n += 3
print(titles)
for percent, fail, title in zip(perc, fails, titles):
    piedata = [percent, (100-int(percent))]

    fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure(figsize=(5, 5))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.pie(piedata)  # this is the information that the circle diagram will be made out of
    ax.legend([('amount of attempts:', NOTT), ('amount of fails', fail)])

    circle = matplotlib.patches.Circle((0, 0), 0.7, color='white')
    ax.add_artist(circle)


    # this is the code for actually putting the circle diagram/pie chart on the screen
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=window)
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack()
    canvas.draw()

    Label(window, text=(title, title), bg='light blue').pack()

    window.mainloop()
    print(percent)
    print(fail)
```

From what I can tell, my problem is at the end with the `window.mainloop()` only being able to be used once and then cannot be used again.

I am trying to get 2 loops out of it currently.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who finds this:
tk.mainloop() (in my case window.mainloop()) stops the program form running in many circumstances. This is a very simplified version of it, but it is likely that if you have come across this, the answer will be to replace it with:

```
  window.update_idletasks()
            window.update()
```

However, if you are using it in a loop, as I was, you will need to add a break clause, or use a for loop, as otherwise it will keep looping.